# Confusión con tipo de variable

Tags: android

En un app deseo enviar una variable `String` usando `Intent` hacia otra `activity`, desde el método `onOptionsItemSelected`, mi problema esta en que la variable se genera en un método `PreferenceFragment`, por más declaraciones que trato de hacer siempre me da error, por que en `PreferenceFragment` la variable  `mconfigenableecox` no es válida (se pinta de rojo), alguien me puede decir cual es mi error y como corregirlo.

Aqui esta mi codigo:

```
public class UsbSettingActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

public String mconfigenableecox = "";

    .
    .
    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_setup_com);

        setHasOptionsMenu( true );
    .
    .
        TwoStatePreference SPconfigenableeco2 = (TwoStatePreference) findPreference("config_enable_eco");
        Boolean mconfigenableecoX = SPconfigenableeco2.isChecked();
        String mconfigenableeco = String.valueOf(mconfigenableecoX);
        mconfigenableecox = mconfigenableeco;
   .
   .
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("EcoSet", mconfigenableecox);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
}
```

Comment: el problema es que estas igualando un `boolean` con un `String` , podrias sin problema mandar el boolean

Comment: Ya encontre el problema, tenía que declarar la variable mconfigenableecox como una variable global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas llamando la variable desde una clase estática,

```
 public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
```

por lo tanto debes definir la variable como estática

```
//public String mconfigenableecox = "";
public static String mconfigenableecox = "";
```